# Power BI: This Calculate returns EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist

Tags: dax, calculated-columns

looking for some help with the error above ive been getting trying to create a calculated column in power BI. im using this function to calculate days in sequence. it returns an error that states i cant refer to an earlier row. any help is appreciated

````
SequenceDays = 
IF (
    'Table'[Group] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Group] ),
    IF (
        DATEDIFF (
            EARLIER ( 'Table'[Date] ),
            'Table'[Date],
            DAY
        ) = 1,
        EARLIER ( 'Table'[SequenceDays] ) + 1,
        1
    ),
    1
)```


The Error occurs in that final Earlier call. Date is in the Date Type, group is Text. thank you!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `EARLIER` to refer to the calculated column you are creating.